# Submitting Wordpress data to database

Tags: php, wordpress

I've encountered a weird problem that I think some of you can help me with.

I'm currently creating a custom Wordpress site where I want to gather some information about my visitors by a multi-page form. So far, so good.

My problem is that I have some checkbox-inputs but in order for the form to submit the clicked inputs correctly, I have to click ALL inputs. I cannot just click one, because then it would fail and it would not get stored in the database. But if all inputs clicked it is submitted and stored correctly.

I submit the code in the following way:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

//checking first page values for empty, if it finds any blank field then redirected to first page

```
    if (isset($_POST['speedpilot'])
        || isset($_POST['gps'])
        || isset($_POST['aircondition'])
        || isset($_POST['parksensor'])
        || isset($_POST['towbar'])){

         //fetching all values posted from first page and inserting it in database
     foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
    }
                        //function to extract array
    extract($_SESSION['post']);  

    $wpdb->insert("detail", array("gps" => $gps, "aircondition" => $aircondition, "parksensor" => $parksensor, "towbar" => $towbar));

    if ($wpdb) {
        echo '<h1 style="color:green;text-align:center;"><span id="success">TILLYKKE!<br/>CARMEDO FINDER DEN BEDSTE BIL TIL DIG</span></h1>'; //gonna be changed
    } else {
        echo '<h1 style="color:red;"><span>Der skete en fejl, pr&oslash;v venligst igen.</span></h1>'; //gonna be changed
    }
                        //destroying session
    unset($_SESSION['post']);

} else {
    $_SESSION['error_page3'] = "Mandatory field(s) are missing, Please fill it again";
    header("location: /side1/");
} ?>
```

Can somebody figure out what I'm currently doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: initialize the variable `$gps = $aircondition = $parksensor = $towbar = "
";` before `extract($_SESSION['post']);`